# The eigenvectors of a matrix and its transpose that correspond to the same eigenvalue are not orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

Spent hours trying to prove this after encountering it in Lax's discussion of the spectral theorem, but no luck. Here's the problem (it is Theorem 18 in Lax 2ed, Chapter 6):

A mapping $A$ has distinct eigenvalues $a_1, ..., a_n$. We know that a matrix has the same eigenvalues as its transpose, so these eigenvalues correspond to the eigenvectors $x_1, ..., x_n$ of $A$, as well as the eigenvectors $y_1, ..., y_n$ of $A^T$.

(1) Show that, for any fixed $i$ in $1, ..., n$, $\langle x_i, y_i\rangle\ne 0$.

(2) Now let $x = \sum{k_jx_j}$ be the expansion of a vector as the sum of the eigenvectors of $A$. Show that $k_i = \dfrac{\langle l_i, x\rangle}{\langle l_i, x_i\rangle}$ for $i=1, ..., n$.

I'm missing something fundamental here. The previous theorem discusses orthogonality of eigenvectors when they do not have the same eigenvalue, but I don't believe it is relevant here.

I also wanted to think about this in terms of the null space of the characteristic polynomials for $A$ and $A^T$ (they obviously have the same roots), but didn't get anywhere there.

Comment: I think that some hypothesis is missing in the discussion. Is your matrix normal?

Comment: No mention of matrix normality. Lax: "the mapping has n distinct eigenvalues." Agreed that the theorem is vague in this sense, this really threw me for a loop.

Comment: The hypothesis that the $n\times n$ matrix has $n$ distinct eigenvalues is surely relevant. But eigenvectors relative to distinct eigenvalues are not necessarily orthogonal. So it's quite strange that this is connected to the spectral theorem without the matrix being normal.

Comment: But eigenvectors of a matrix and its transpose related to distinct eigenvalues (e.g. $x_i$ and $y_j$) are, in fact, orthogonal. Andreas uses this in his answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Either there should be an additional hypothesis, or you should be allowed to choose the eigenvectors cleverly in the case where several eigenvalues are equal.  As it stands, there are easy counterexamples: Let $A$ be the zero matrix or the identity matrix.  then the $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s could be anything, and in particular you could have unwanted orthogonality.

EDIT, after the question was edited to say the eigenvalues are distinct: Now that the necessary hypotheses are in place, the result can be proved as follows.  First show that the eigenvectors $x_i$ and $y_j$ for *different* eigenvalues *are* orthogonal. Indeed, (taking the vectors to be column  vectors)
$$
a_jy_j^Tx_i=(y_j^TA)x_i=y_j^T(Ax_i)=a_iy_j^Tx_i,
$$
and $a_j\neq a_i$, so $y_j^Tx_i=0$.  Now if $x_i$ were also orthogonal to $y_i$, then it would be orthogonal to all the $y$'s.  But these form a basis for the space, so $x_i$ would be orthogonal to everything, including itself.  That would make $x_i=0$, which is false because $x_i$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Good point, actually. These matrices are actually excluded from the theorem because 0 and I do not have distinct eigenvalues (which the theorem calls for). I didn't include this in the original post, so I've edited it. Sorry for the confusion.