# Relation between projection method and valuation map for generating the Rauzy Fractal

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, projective-geometry, fractals

In my research I am studying the tribonacci substitution $\sigma : \mathcal{A}^* \to \mathcal{A}$
$$
\sigma(0) = 01, \qquad \sigma(1) = 02, \qquad \sigma(2) = 0,
$$
where $\mathcal{A} = \{0,1,2\}$ is the alphabet and $\mathcal{A}^*$ denotes the set of all finite words with letters in $\mathcal{A}$. This substitution rule is related to the polynomial equation $x^3=x^2+x+1$, with real root $\beta = 1.8392...$, called the *tribonacci constant*. The incidence matrix $M$, the linear map associated to $\sigma$ by abelianisation, is given by
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix $M$ is Pisot, what means that there is only one eigenvalue with $|\lambda|>1$ and the corresponding eigenspace has dimension 1. In this case this eigenvalue is the tribonacci constant $\beta>1$ with eigenvector $\vec{v} = (\beta^2,\beta,1)^T$, which spans the unstable (expanding) eigenspace $E^u$. The other two eigenvalues of $M$ obey $|\lambda|<1$ and span the stable (contracting) eigenspace $E^s$. The fixed point of $\sigma$ is called the tribonacci word and is given by
$$w = 010201001020101020100102010...$$
Now let $\vec{e_i}$, with $i=0,1,2$ be the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, one defines a stair of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by
$$
\vec{x_m} = \sum^m_{j=1} \vec{e_{w_j}},
$$
where $w_j$ is the $j$th symbol in $w$ and $m \geq 0$. From $w$, a so-called [Rauzy fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauzy_fractal) can be constructed in two ways: 1) project $\vec{x}_m$ along $\vec{v}$ onto $E^s$ for all $m \geq 0$, or 2) use the *valuation map*.

Method 1) is the common way to construct Rauzy fractals according to literature [2,3]. Method 2) is dealt with in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264647/what-method-is-used-for-projecting-the-rauzy-fractal/1264809#1264809) and in this paper [1]. I have been able to generate a Rauzy fractal method 2) that is perfectly self-similar in the way that the tiles are perfect copies of each other, up to a scaling factor: [My figure of the Rauzy fractal with valuation map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW0CC.jpg)

When I use method 1), I do get a Rauzy fractal, but it is skewed. By this I mean that it is still a Rauzy fractal that tiles the plane, but its three domains are not simply scaled versions of each other, but are rather related by a more general affine transformation: [My figure of a Rauzy fractal by projecting along unstable eigenspace onto stable eigenspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xb6Z.png)

The problem is, the "correct" Rauzy fractal, with up to scaling identical domains as obtained from method 2), is depicted in literature and *claimed to be obtained from method 1).*

My question is now: **does method 1) indeed produce a skewed version of the "correct" Rauzy fractal, or am I doing something wrong?**

[1] Sirvent, V. F., & Wang, Y. (2002). Self-affine tiling via substitution dynamical systems and Rauzy fractals. Pacific journal of mathematics, 206(2), 465-485.

[2] Fogg, N. P., Berthé, V., Ferenczi, S., Mauduit, C., & Siegel, A. (Eds.). (2002). Substitutions in dynamics, arithmetics and combinatorics. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer Berlin Heidelberg.

[3] Arnoux, P., & Ito, S. (2001). Pisot substitutions and Rauzy fractals. Bulletin of the Belgian Mathematical Society-Simon Stevin, 8(2), 181-207.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've generated pretty much the same pictures. I guess you already saw [the image in the other post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Nko.png) that I generated with the valuation map. I also generated [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRVGv.png) using the projection technique. The projection image lives in the 2D plane spanned by real and imaginary parts of the complex eigenvector in 3D space. The viewpoint is orthogonal to the image so I think it should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! This is indeed what I observe as well. Are you aware of any relation between the left eigenvectors of $M$ (used for valuation) and the right eigenvectors (used for projection)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Krebbo - I had to wrap my head around the problem. In answer to your question, yes there are relationships between left and right eigenvectors or, put another way, between eigenvectors for a matrix and its transpose. That figures crucially the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pictures are exactly correct. The difference between the two images arises because one is an oblique projection and the other is an orthogonal projection. Thus, the pictures are quite similar in appearance but somewhat distorted.

You've described Rauzy's original construction perfectly: We project the staircase *along* the real eigenvector of $M$ and *onto* the two dimensional stable subspace spanned by the real and imaginary parts of a complex eigenvector. Let us emphasize the fact that the stable space need not be orthogonal to the real eigenvector and, in fact, is not in this case. The projection is oblique.

Next, the valuation map can also be thought of as a projection. This time though, we project onto the one-dimensional space spanned by one of the complex eigenvectors of $M^T$. Of course, $M$ and $M^T$ have the same eigenvalues but different eigenvectors. Furthermore, if $\vec{v}$ is an eigenvector of $M$ and $\vec{v}_T$ is an eigenvector of $M^T$ corresponding to different eigenvalues, then [they are orthogonal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579826/). Thus, this projection is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Especially the insight of the left- and right eigenvectors proves to be useful for me :).

Comment: I'm glad it helped @Krebbo! I reread my [old response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264647#1264809) and was really not quite happy with it. So I updated it to include both projection techniques. There's also a link to some [computer code](https://observablehq.com/d/28d955eb226a309d), if you care about that aspect of it.